# Cleanly access array of structures based on a value

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, embedded

I'm trying to create an array of structures, where one entry is created for every device that joins in the network with the one that is running the program. This array should be accessed with the network address of the interested device.

Example: there are three (other) devices on the network, with addresses 0x1, 0x2 and 0x3 (we're running on 0x0). Now we want to access the data structure related with device 0x1, which let's suppose is Table[0]. The problem is to associate the address (`0x1`) with the index (`0`).

NOTE: the network addresses are dynamically assigned by other parts of the software and are *not*  under my control. They are also *not* guaranteed to be sequential.

What is the cleanest way to do this?

The most intuitive way to me is to search the whole table comparing the `Address` field of each entry with the specific address (in the example `0x1`), and then returning the index, but I was wondering if there is a more appropriate way to do this common operation. Which, by the way, probably has a proper name (dynamic data structure?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **Quick, simple & dirty method**. If the addresses are small numbers, you can simply make a lookup table such as:

```
const struct_ptr* TABLE[n] =
{
  NULL,
  &struct_this,
  &struct_that,
  NULL,
  ...
};
```

Where the index corresponds to an address. If the address has a corresponding struct, you get a pointer to the struct, otherwise NULL.

That's the fastest possible way, it has direct access *O(1)*. But it wastes a bit of data memory and is not really feasible if your addresses could be any kind of numbers.

2) **Sorted lookup table and binary search**. Use this if the addresses are any kind of numbers. In that case, you will have to make a lookup table consisting only of pointers to existing structs such as:

```
const struct_ptr* TABLE [NUMBER_OF_EXISTING_STRUCTS] = 
{
  &struct_this,
  &struct_that,
  ...
};
```

Each struct needs to have a member `address` and they have to be added to the above lookup table in a sorted way, lowest address first. You can then binary search through the table, with a comparison function which compares each struct `address` member. This is fairly quick, *O(log n)*.

3) **Hash table.** The most advanced alternative. This works best for systems with huge amounts of data and can also handle duplicates. Access time is nearly deterministic, close to O(log n), but not quite. Depends on how you implement "chaining" and such.

Comment: Thank you! Please note that the addresses are assigned somewhere else and are not controllable. Therefore I can't expect them to be sequential, so I guess I have to implement 2 or 3. I've edited the question with the (important) addition.

Comment: @clabacchio I'd say 2) is most likely and it is suitable for embedded systems, since it is 100% deterministic. Hash tables often rely on dynamic memory allocation and are probably overkill in your case.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion, I don't need sophisticate addressing since the entries are so few. Thanks a lot for the thorough answer.

Comment: @clabacchio If you go with (2), you probably want to start with `qsort` and `bsearch` standard library functions. You only have to implement the comparison function, so it's a relatively fast start.

Comment: @user694733 `qsort` shouldn't be needed since the structs and their addresses are known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

May not be a definitive answer, but I found a hint that there may not be a better solution that manually searching the index.

On cprogramming.com, regarding [Hash tables](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/computersciencetheory/hash-table.html):

> One of the biggest drawbacks to a language like C is that there are no keyed arrays. In a normal C array (also called an indexed array), the only way to access an element would be through its index number.

Therefore I have to actually scan the array for an entry with that address and get the index from it.

Comment: This is not really a language weakness, because if you implement something such as C++ std::map in the language, then uses lets say strings as index, the compiler would still have to implement this as some sort of hash table. So just because there is no language support for it in C, it doesn't mean that the same code written in another language will be any faster than your manual C solution. The only difference between C and other languages here, is that C forces you to write the code yourself.

Comment: (But of course, writing your own hash table for every project is far from ideal, when you could be spending your time on the actual application instead. Plus it is probably better to have some algorithm guru write the hash table for you and test it, rather than to hack up something of your own, which may have bugs and performance glitches.)

Comment: @Lundin well I guess I'll have to put something together, it's not going to be a large table (less than 10 entries), and I'm on my own in this.